# mailx output in color format

Tags: colors, output, mailx

I've a code which 'grep' certain strings from two files which I've defined as variables and if those strings are found then it'll send me the last 10 lines of the files using `tail`. I want the strings in my output mail in green color format. Is this anyway possible?
Below is my code:

```
grep "xyz" $File2
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Process finished, Below are the logs : \n `tail $File2` |mailx -s "Logs" user1@ace.com
else
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You'd probably have to generate full HTML output for that. ANSI terminal escape sequences (which do the coloring) aren't understood by any mail client I'm aware of.